# Rearranging rows based on values in a column in a 2d array in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, columnsorting

I am trying to sort a 2d array based on the values of the last column in descending order. My code goes as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define totrow 10
#define totcolumn 6
float grade[totrow][totcolumn];
void reArg (float grade[][totcolumn]);

void reArg (float grade[][totcolumn])
{
   int temp, x, k = 5;

   for (int r = 0; r < totrow; r++)
   {
      for (int c = 0; c <totcolumn;c++)
      {
          if (grade[r][k] > grade[c][k])
          {
              for(x = 0; x < totcolumn;x++)
              {
                  temp = grade[r][x];
                  grade[r][x]=grade[c][x];
                  grade[c][x]=temp;
              }
          }
      }
   }
   for (int r = 0; r < totrow; r++)
   {
       for (int c = 0; c < totcolumn; c++)
       {
           printf("%.2f\t",grade[r][c]);
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
}
```

After the code compiles I get this for my array:

```
7899.00 92.00 90.00 88.00 86.00 89.00
6814.00 85.00 86.00 92.00 88.00 87.00
8234.00 77.00 87.00 84.00 98.00 86.00
7654.00 76.00 87.00 84.00 88.00 83.00
3534.00 86.00 81.00 84.00 73.00 81.00
7284.00 56.00 81.00 87.00 98.00 80.00
9901.00 45.00 78.00 79.00 80.00 70.00
6465.00 87.00 54.00 68.00 72.00 70.00
7934.00 76.00 91.00 84.00 65.00 79.00
7234.00 76.00 81.00 84.00 78.00 79.00
```

The orginal array is:

```
6814.00 85.00 86.00 92.00 88.00 87.75
7234.00 76.00 81.00 84.00 78.00 79.75
6465.00 87.00 54.00 68.00 72.00 70.25
7899.00 92.00 90.00 88.00 86.00 89.00
9901.00 45.00 78.00 79.00 80.00 70.50
8234.00 77.00 87.00 84.00 98.00 86.50
7934.00 76.00 91.00 84.00 65.00 79.00
7284.00 56.00 81.00 87.00 98.00 80.50
7654.00 76.00 87.00 84.00 88.00 83.75
3534.00 86.00 81.00 84.00 73.00 81.00
```

Why does the program only sort the first 6 rows?

the complete code is: https://repl.it/@ryanw123/project-4

Comment: What happens if you change to `#define totrow 9
#define totcolumn 5` for an experiment?

Comment: The original array loses the last two values.

Comment: Your code seems incomplete by at least a `}` (assuming it is not a mistake in my edit), please get the shown code compileable, create a [mcve].

Comment: You're right the last line should have a } I didn't include that in my post. The code does compile on my compiler and it will print the results. I believe the problem is within the if statement since r will eventually be less than c.

Comment: "it will print the results" I doubt it, without a `main()` and without values in any array. Please create an [mcve] to demonstrate your observations.

Comment: I added the repl.it of my complete program.

Comment: Not all of your program, not an external link. An MCVE, directly in your question.

Comment: This functions objective is to arrange the original matrix based on the value of the last column in descending order. I am only getting the the sorting to occur in the first 6 rows after my code has run. I believe I need to change my if statement, but I am not sure. I am getting a clean compile when I run this function with the main,

Comment: Thank you user3121023 That was the issue

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you were using `for(int c = 0; c < totcolumn; c++)`, but, as I figured you were trying to make a [Bubble Sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), you need to go through the rows twice, like this: `for(int c = 0; c < totrow; c++)`.

I created an example to run locally.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define totrow 4
#define totcolumn 2


void reArg (float grade[][totcolumn]) {
   int temp, x, k = 5;

   for (int r = 0; r < totrow; r++) {
      for (int c = 0; c < totrow; c++) {
          if (grade[r][k] > grade[c][k]) {
              for(x = 0; x < totcolumn ; x++) {
                  temp = grade[r][x];
                  grade[r][x]=grade[c][x];
                  grade[c][x]=temp;
              }
          }
      }
   }

   for (int r = 0; r < totrow; r++) {
       for (int c = 0; c < totcolumn; c++) {
           printf("%.2f\t",grade[r][c]);
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
}


int main() {

    float grade[totrow][totcolumn] = {{1,2},{3,4},{0,0}};

    reArg(grade);

    return 0;
}
```